# MYSQL/MardiaDB 'recycle bin'

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb, restore, recycle

I'm using MardiaDB and i'm wondering if there is a way how to install a 'recycle bin' on my server where if someone deleted a table or anything it gets shifted to the recycle bin and restoring it is easy.

Not talking about mounting things to restore it and all that stuff but litterly a 'save place' where it gets stored (i have more then enough space) until i decide to delete it or just keep it there for 24 hours.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such feature exists.  http://bugs.mysql.com takes "feature requests".

Such a feature would necessarily involve MySQL; it cannot be done entirely in the OS's filesystem.  This is because a running mysql caches information in RAM that the FS does not know about.  And because the information about a table/db/proc/trigger/etc is not located entirely in a single file.  Instead extra info exists in other, more general, files.

With MyISAM, your goal was partially possible in the fs.  A MyISAM table was composed of 3 files: `.frm`, `.MYD',`.MYI`.  Still MySQL would need to flush something to forget that it know about the table before the fs could move the 3 files somewhere else.  MyISAM is going away; so don't even think about using that 'Engine'.

In InnoDB, a table is composed of a `.ibd` file (if using file_per_table) plus a `.frm` file, plus some info in the communal `ibdata1` file.  If the table is `PARTITIONed`, the layout is more complex.

In version 8.0, most of the previous paragraph will become incorrect -- a major change is occurring.

"Transactions" are a way of undoing writes to a table...

```
BEGIN;
INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/etc...
if ( change-mind )
    then ROLLBACK;
    else COMMIT;
```

Effectively, the undo log acts as a recycle bin -- but only at the record level, and only until you execute `COMMIT`.

MySQL 8.0 will add the ability to have DDL statements (eg, `DROP TABLE`) in a transaction.  But, again, it is only until `COMMIT`.

Think of `COMMIT` as flushing the recycle bin.

Comment: Do you maybe know of any Linux based extension that can do such a thing?

Comment: Not possible in Linux.  See my addition.

Comment: I gave you my 'answer' vote.  To bad though.. I mean it would solve a lot of issues and i guess mysql could just integrate an option to set a max size recycle bin (and if it gets bigger then the max size just delete the oldest information) or something like that. But yet again i don't know anything about their code.

Comment: @SwAt.Be - I added some more -- maybe a little bit of what you want is in "transactions"?

Comment: So if i'm right you need to disable autocommit and then you can use the transactions? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Comment: `BEGIN` (aka `START TRANSACTION`) overrides `autocommit`.